# command line locally using wamp

Tags: shell, command-line, wamp

When referring to this post here:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today/

it tells you to run php -q path\to\server.php from shell using XAMPP, is there an alternative for WAMP?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It might be useful to register php.exe as an ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE so the command line can recognize the 'php' command instead of needing to enter the full path '\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8\php' as the command.

To do this, you can follow the steps outlined on this page: http://windows.fyicenter.com/view.php?ID=60. Except for Step 5, enter the path of WAMP's php.exe instead. For example, just add in `$;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8` to the Variable value field. And each time you open up your command line, just run php using

```
php pageYouAreRunning.php
```

..still keeping in mind that the pageYouAreRunning.php is relative to the current path in your command line.

Answer (score 3):

It's essentially the same thing as described. You will need to open the windows cmd shell, and then you just need to find the location of the php file on your particular installation.

In the wamp installation I have it's located at `\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8\php`. So to run the php script I want, I would call...

```
\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8\php pageYouAreRunning.php
```

Keep in mind `pageYouAreRunning.php` is relative to the path you are currently in in your shell console.

Answer (score 3):

It's no longer recommended to edit your environment path to directly point to the path to the PHP exe. This can cause you headaches further down the line.

A moderator named RiggsFoley over at the [WampServer forum](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,150875#msg-150907) shared the following file 
called `phppath.cmd`:

```
@echo off

REM **********************************************************************
REM * PLACE This file in a folder that is already on your PATH
REM * Or just put it in your C:\Windows folder as that is on the
REM * Serch path by default
REM * - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
REM * EDIT THE NEXT 3 Parameters to fit your installed WAMPServer
REM * for example I installed WAMPServer on the D: drive you may
REM * have used C:
REM * - baseWamp : is the drive and folder where you installed WAMPServer
REM * - defaultPHPver : is the version of PHP that will be pathed
REM *                   if no Parameter is put on the bat file
REM * - composerInstalled : Where I insatlled composerInstalled
REM * - phpFolder : The folder structure that contains the Multiple
REM *               possible version of PHP I have installed
REM **********************************************************************


set baseWamp=D:\wamp
set defaultPHPver=7.0.23
set composerInstalled=%baseWamp%\composer
set phpFolder=\bin\php\php

if %1.==. (
    set phpver=%baseWamp%%phpFolder%%defaultPHPver%
) else (
    set phpver=%baseWamp%%phpFolder%%1
)

PATH=%PATH%;%phpver%
php -v
echo ---------------------------------------------------------------


REM IF PEAR IS INSTALLED IN THIS VERSION OF PHP

IF exist %phpver%\pear (
    set PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR=D:\wamp\bin\php\php%phpver%
    set PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR=D:\wamp\bin\php\php%phpver%\pear
    set PHP_PEAR_DOC_DIR=D:\wamp\bin\php\php%phpver%\docs
    set PHP_PEAR_BIN_DIR=D:\wamp\bin\php\php%phpver%
    set PHP_PEAR_DATA_DIR=D:\wamp\bin\php\php%phpver%\data
    set PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN=D:\wamp\bin\php\php%phpver%\php.exe
    set PHP_PEAR_TEST_DIR=D:\wamp\bin\php\php%phpver%\tests

    echo PEAR INCLUDED IN THIS CONFIG
    echo ---------------------------------------------------------------
) else (
    echo PEAR DOES NOT EXIST IN THIS VERSION OF php
    echo ---------------------------------------------------------------
)

REM IF COMPOSER EXISTS ADD THAT TOO
REM **************************************************************
REM * IF A GLOBAL COMPOSER EXISTS ADD THAT TOO
REM *
REM * This assumes that composer is installed in /wamp/composer
REM *
REM **************************************************************
IF EXIST %composerInstalled% (
    ECHO COMPOSER INCLUDED IN THIS CONFIG
    echo ---------------------------------------------------------------
    set COMPOSER_HOME=%baseWamp%\composer
    set COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR=%baseWamp%\composer

    PATH=%PATH%;%baseWamp%\composer

    rem echo TO UPDATE COMPOSER do > composer self-update
    echo ---------------------------------------------------------------
) else (
    echo ---------------------------------------------------------------
    echo COMPOSER IS NOT INSTALLED
    echo ---------------------------------------------------------------
)

set baseWamp=
set defaultPHPver=
set composerInstalled=
set phpFolder=
```

As per the instructions, you need to edit the `baseWamp` and `defaultPHPver` variables. Check Wamp's `bin\php` directory for the available PHP version numbers.

Put the file in your `C:\Windows` directory, then open a new command window, and type `phppath`. You will now have `php` available during that window's session.

Answer (score 2):

Not tested, but I would say it is the same...

There is a "php.exe" in your wamp/php folder...

Run it through commandline :

```
cd mywamp/php

php -q file.php
```

Comment: doesn't seem to do anything :-(

Answer (score 1):

If php isn't running at all, create a batch file with the following code, and save it in your global folder as 'php'.

```
"c:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.29\php.exe" $1 ${2} ${3} ${4}
```

Of course replace php7.0.29 with whatever your php version on your machine is
Then just run any php command like normal, e.g.

```
php -v
```

If you need more arguments, just keep adding them as optional e.g. ${5} ${6}

Answer (score 0):

Without modifying anything in Win.
First check which version you are using in Wamp, then then run the command from PHP's Wamp folder for example:

`C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.33\php -v`

For example, if you should run a Magento command (but this is true for any other CMS or PHP software) you place yourself in the folder where you have the CMS installation and run the command

`C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.33\php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

I use Git Bash on windows and was facing same problem, after looking around I have devised my own solution.

I created a .bashrc, saved it in my home folder and still has little problems but this is my first time in bash scripting, still it might help someone else.

```
#!/bin/bash

default_php=php8.1.0;
default_mysql=mysql5.7.36;

php_folder=/c/wamp64/bin/php/;
mysql_folder=/c/wamp64/bin/mysql/;

current_folder=$PWD;

main_link_folder=/c/Scripts;
link_php=www;
link_mysql=db;

# In this case I would add C:\Scripts\www to my PATH variable

echo "PHP CLI Version: ${default_php//[!.0-9]/}, to change press P";
echo "MySQL CLI Version: ${default_mysql//[!.0-9]/}, to change press M";
echo '____________________________________';

while : ; do
    read -s -n 1 k <&1
    if [[ $k = p ]] ; then

        for entry in "$php_folder"/*
        do 
            if [[ ! $entry == *.txt ]]; then
                arrVar[${#arrVar[@]}]=$(basename $entry)
            fi
        done
        for i in "${!arrVar[@]}"
            do   
            echo "$i : PHP  ${arrVar[$i]//[!.0-9]/}"
        done
        read -s -n 1 opt <&1
        if [ "${arrVar[opt]+abc}" ]; then
                cd $main_link_folder
                    rm -rf $link_php
                    ln -rsfT $php_folder${arrVar[$opt]} $link_php
                cd $current_folder
                    alias mysql="winpty $mysql_folder$default_mysql/bin/mysql.exe"
                return
        else
            cd $main_link_folder
                rm -rf $link_php
                ln -rsfT $php_folder$default_php $link_php
            cd $current_folder
                alias mysql="winpty $mysql_folder$default_mysql/bin/mysql.exe"
            return
        fi
    else
        cd $main_link_folder
        rm -rf $link_php
        ln -rsfT $php_folder$default_php $link_php
        cd $current_folder
            alias mysql="winpty $mysql_folder$default_mysql/bin/mysql.exe"
        return
    fi
done
break
```

I just saved this script in my user folder and it loads everytime i open git bash, neat!

My problem is solved.

Any suggestions or further improvements are welcome.

Thank you all