# Installing Composer in WAMP PHP Google+ Project, PHP is not recognised

Tags: php, wampserver, composer-php

I am following [this PHP Google+ tutorial](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/php) and I am trying to install composer in my WAMP directory

```
C:\wamp\www\gplus-quickstart-php>curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

but I'm getting this error

> 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable
>   program or batch file.

How do I resolve this problem? I already have PHP installed (via WAMP Server). Do I have to install PHP in my computer as well?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok a couple of things you need to do here.

First windows does not have a curl processor like unix so you need to use the other option for installing Composer

```
php -r "eval('?>'.file_get_contents('https://getcomposer.org/installer'));"
```

For this to work you need the php.exe processor to be on your path, so you have 2 options here. Either add the `c:\wamp\bin\php\phpx.y.z` folder to your PATH ***thats the bad option for WAMPServer*** as you can have more than one version of PHP installed and when you activate another version your PATH will still be pointing at the Old version. Or my prefered option write yourself a little .cmd file which will do it for you like this

filename = addphp.cmd

```
PATH=%PATH%;c:\wamp\bin\php\phpx.y.z
```

Put this file in a folder already registered on your path so you can run it from anywhere in a command window.

Now you will have to edit the \wamp\bin\php\phpx.y.z\php.ini file. This is similiar to the one used by php code run through the Apache web server but is only used by the PHP CLI (Command Line Interpreter)

Make sure the extension php_curl is uncommented or the above line wont work i.e. remove the `;` comment symbol

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

So now run a command window, cd into the folder that you want composer installed into and run the command above, then follow the rest of the install instructions on [Install instructions](http://getcomposer.org/download/)

Comment: +1 Thank you so very much. It worked! I loved your preferred method of using `addphp.cmd`. Very helpful answer!

Comment: Very helpful for this answer

Comment: It will not working on latest laravel  version... how i install latest laravel version into my wamp....

Comment: @RiggsFolly I realise this is a very old question but I'm having the same issue but I am using XAMPP instead of WAMP and there is no bin folder with my Xampp directory. Could you provide any guidance on that?

Comment: @user2363025 Just work out where `php.exe` lives on a XAMPP install and change the `PATH` statement to use that directory path instead of the one I used above for a WAMPServer install.

Answer (score 10):

On windows, just installed composer with windows installer -> easy and with wizard - like it.

https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe

Answer (score 1):

first you have to add your php path to system 
after go to php.ini and rmove `;` for `extension=php_openssl.dll` it will be active
3 run this command in cmd :

```
php -r "eval('?>'.file_get_contents('https://getcomposer.org/installer'));"
```

Answer (score 1):

If using phpstorm you can download composer using their built in composer option in the tools menu.

You can run it from CLI by locating your php.exe, e.g

`C:\wamp\bin\php\php7\php.exe composer.phar install`

Answer (score 0):

No idea if anyone will answer this late but I'm having issues with this.  I created the .cmd file and put in the path as suggested.  I put this file in my wamp\www\sitename folder.  Is that not what you mean when you say putting it in a "registered path folder"?  After creating the file, and running the code it still says php not recognized.

Comment: No. Put it in a folder that already exists on your windows PATH. From cmd window keyin `echo %PATH%`, look for a folder already in that list. Use `C:\windows` if you nothing else of your own making on the path. Dont put `C:\wamp` anything on the path.

Answer (score 0):

First, to get php into your path see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727436/how-to-properly-set-php-environment-variable-to-run-commands-in-git-bash?answertab=active#tab-top)

Installing composer is explained nicely [here](https://getcomposer.org/download/) (code below just for illustration. Be sure to get latest from the link)

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'e115a8dc7871f15d853148a7fbac7da27d6c0030b848d9b3dc09e2a0388afed865e6a3d6b3c0fad45c48e2b5fc1196ae') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

A quick check to confirm it worked:

```
    $ php composer.phar --version
    Composer version 1.2.1 2016-09-12 11:27:19
```