# Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, guzzle

I am using BOTH [Guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and Codeigniter 3.0 for the first time. Also I admit I am using php namespace for the first time.

I am trying to make a very simple get request using Guzzle according to the examples provided in the docs. (The Guzzle docs say nothing about codeigniter).

The Guzzle files are located at application/class/guzzle

Here is my very simple controller

```
public function indey () {

        $data = array();
        $data['main_content'] = "hiview";
        $data['title'] = "Data Analyzer - Welcome";
        $data['xas'] = $this->guzzler();
        $this->load->view('template', $data);
    }

    private function guzzler() {
        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client;
        $response = $client->get('http://guzzlephp.org');
        return $response;
    }
```

This is my simple view

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
             <h1>Hi</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h1><?php var_dump($xas); ?></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the error I am getting

**A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Error
Message: Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found
Filename: controllers/hello.php
Line Number: 22
Backtrace:**

Comment: Quick question; why not use Composer to manage Guzzle?

Comment: Failed to install Composer on wamp and windows 7. Tried both installer and command line ...

Comment: Ok, that's a decent reason. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18786420/899126) might help get composer set up, but I'm unfortunately not familiar with how CodeIgniter is set up. It may have to go into application/libraries, though (and from there, loaded by `$this->load->library('GuzzleHttp')` or something like that)

Comment: Thanks for the composer setup link Chris ... and yeah i'm trying to figure out the "something like that" :)

Comment: @ChrisForrence ... Your composer setup link really helped ... Thank you :)

Answer (score 8):

In `application/config/config.php`

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = FCPATH.'vendor/autoload.php';
```

it work fine for me

Comment: Thank you very much that helped me a lot !!

Answer (score 4):

You should load it in your controller methods where needed or if desired, autoload it. I use the former:
First: use install it using composer in the application folder:

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:~6.0
```

Second: Let CI autoload composer (applications/config/config.php)

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;
```

Then in your controller

```
 public function guzzler_get($url, $uri)
{    
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => $url]);
    $response = $client->get($uri);
    // print_r($response); // print out response

    // print out headers: 
    // foreach ($response->getHeaders() as $name => $values) {
    //    echo $name . ': ' . implode(', ', $values) . "\r\n";
    // }
    return $response;
}
```

Use:

```
$your_var = $this->guzzler_get('http://httpbin.org', '/html');
```

You now have the response in the `$your_var` variable. For the rest, check the documentation. Otherwise use a "friendlier" method/library for your http requests like [CodeIgniter-cURL](https://goo.gl/alON8N) or [Requests](http://goo.gl/Fy58pP)

Answer (score 2):

I solved adding following instruction at the beginning of my .php file:

```
require 'C:/php/vendor/autoload.php';
```

but I'm not sure it's a good practice...

Answer (score 0):

Add it:
require_once (**DIR** . "/vendor/autoload.php");