# Where Can I Directly Download Laravel Dependency Folders/Files from without using composer

Tags: laravel, vendor

For some reason, composer cannot work on my PC and wamp also (for now) so I downloaded the laravel zip folder, "laravel-master.zip".

I unzipped and uploaded this folder to my online production server but I noticed that I do not have the vendor folder. It was not included in the laravel-master folder.

So my question is... from where can I get the vendor folder (and any other folders/files) so I can manually add them to my laravel installation?

Comment: don't think it's a good idea - this folder is really dynamic and changes almost every week with package updates. And also composer must generate autoload files for you to make laravel work

Comment: If you had installed laravel, then you can use Laravel without installing.at least once, installation must be done.

Comment: If you want  to continue to use Laravel is a MUST to use Composer. You are probably making some mistakes while trying to install it. So you can better go to the Composer website and search for help on how to install the composer.phar first. In the vendor folder is also located the symphony folder which is very important to Laravel

Comment: What happens when you type `composer` from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

I will follow the same logic as the other saying. It is useless (and this is not recommended) to copy the vendor files because they are updated frequently and not stored.

the problem is that without composer, it will be difficult to work with Laravel (not only for class loading, but also unable to share your project later).

To use composer with WAMP, you probably forgot to specify during the installation, the php.exe WAMP to use. Located in C:\wamp\bin\php\phpx.y.z.

Here are two links that will help you achieve this. (You can uninstall your composer before to start from scratch)

[Question and Answer about use composer in WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777396/installing-composer-in-wamp-php-google-project-php-is-not-recognised)

[Video about install composer and use it in WAMP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0e3MrHu-wY)

Then you just might be in the root of your project a composer update.