# Executing a PHP script from C++ Program?

Tags: php, c++, parsing, post, console

I'm trying to execute a PHP Script and run it from a C++ program
here's my code
C++:

```
cout << std::system("php -f http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php");
```

but it gives me this in the cmd window
'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

any herlp?
thank you

Comment: Do you have php installed on your system? I think yes, but if you want to call php so, you have to register an environment variable. Take a look at **[this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727436/how-to-properly-set-php-environment-variable-to-run-commands-in-git-bash)**

Answer (score 1):

The PHP executable obviously isn't in your path.