# Cron Job in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, cron

I create a console command in my project. I want it to be executed everyday at 7 p.m. How could i do it in symfony2? A basic php cron job way or symfony2 have something more convenient?
Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the basic **cron**. On *debian* or *ubuntu* you can do this:

```
crontab -e -u <username>
```

Where *username* is the name of the user that should execute the command.
In the editor add your command. Here is [a good explanation](http://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html) how the line should look. For a Symfony2 command something like this should work:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/symfony2/app/console your:command --option=123
```

This will execute `your:command --option=123` every minute.

---

On a *windows* machine you can use the `ac` command. It is available for *windows 7* by default. [Read the docs here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726974.aspx). It should look something like this:

```
AT 00:00 /every:M,T,W,Th,F "php /var/www/symfony2/app/console your:command --option=123"
```

Make sure that `php` is [available globaly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16289254/1847340) or the path to the `php.exe` file is correct.

Comment: My os is window7. I can't ran the crontab command directly. Then what should i do? Thank you for ur answer. @byf-ferdy

Answer (score 2):

You can just set a cron in crontab to execute your symfony command,

e.g.

0 19 * * * /var/www/symfony/app/console YOUR_COMMAND

Comment: Nop, you must run the command as www-data user, else it could break the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good question.

I recently did some work (using ZF1 components, not full MVC) where all kinds of hidden dependencies existed on cron jobs to perform tasks, and I had to spend much time adding comments and creating documentation to warn anyone coming after me what these crons existed, what they did, where they were stored and so on.

It never dawned on me that there would be a ZF component just for that purpose, lots of dependencies on controllers though...

Sorry I'm not answering your direct question though.

FWIW

Comment: Your link is outdated.

Comment: Is this an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the user you use to execute the command. If you run it as root, root could own Symfony cache then break your site HTTP side (because nginx will run as www-data user for example).

With Docker, I am using phusion base image "setuser" method to force www-data user.