# Cloning a Laravel project into VSCode

Tags: php, laravel, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to clone a Laravel project into VSCode and run the project on a local server. I have imported Remote - WSL, but it won't let me set up a composer. I get: [this error message when using php command in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFFqZ.png)

I don't know what to do from here. Is there any other way to simply clone a project?

Comment: That error look like it is TEXT. So post it as text into your question please. Pictures of code/data/errors are not recomended

Comment: Looks to me like you dont have php on your path

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a PHP program from command prompt on a Windows Machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415052/how-to-run-a-php-program-from-command-prompt-on-a-windows-machine)

Answer (score 0):

A popular option is to use a pre-configured program like MAMP / WAMP / XAMP which gives you the stack you need to run php code locally.

Alternatively you can set up you local environment for php and solve the error you are getting...

The error suggests you need to install php globally on your system :
https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.macosx.php

And to install composer:
https://www.hostinger.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-install-composer