# Bake with Cakephp 3.4 on Windows 10 using wamp

Tags: windows, cakephp, wamp

I'm trying to setup baking with Cakephp 3.4 on a Windows 10 machine using wamp. So first let me start with the paths that I'm using.

Path to Wamp is: C:\wamp

Path to PHP is: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25

Path to cakephp project fold is: C:\wamp\www

Path to current cakephp project is: C:\wamp\www\BrandInnovation

Path to cake, cake.bat and cake.php files is: C:\wamp\www\BrandInnovation\bin

So I remember in 2.x you had to set Windows Environment Variables to have it work. It was something like `c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25\;c:\wamp\www\cake\console\` in the advanced system settings in windows. My problem is that in Cakephp 3.x I dont see the \cake\Console anymore in any of the sites files.

If I open the Command Prompt in windows and navigate to C:\wamp\www\BrandInnovation\bin and execute the cake.bat file I get

> C:\wamp\www\BrandInnovation\bin>cake.bat 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Any and all help would be great and thanks.

Comment: From default installation, I am able to run `bin\cake bake ...` and it would work. If you `cd C:\wamp\www\BrandInnovation` and run your command it should work. due to your error `'php' is not recognized` I would say this is a PHP installation issue, not a CakePHP issue.

Comment: I dont think that is the case as I can see the sites locally in my browser, if PHP was not working then the sites would not work or would wamp. Pretty sure it a path or windows environment variable problem.

Comment: I'm not saying you don't have php installed, I think the environment path for PHP is not working. In your cmd type 'php -v'

Comment: WAMPServer does not and SHOULD NOT put the PHP folder on  the Windows PATH envronment variable. It would TOTALLY DESTROY the ability of WAMPServer to easily switch versions of PHP

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597067/how-to-run-php-from-windows-command-line/16289254#16289254

Comment: Note: PHP used by Apache is not quite the same thing as PHP CLI used from the command line.

Comment: Thanks RiggsFolly,
I was able to make a phppath.cmd file with the code below 

PATH=%PATH%;c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.x.y
php -v

I then navigated in the cmd file in the command prompt and ran it, then I navigated to C:\wamp\www\BrandInnovation\bin and rand "cake bake" and it work!