# How to set php version for composer when having multiple xampp versions?

Tags: php, xampp, composer-php

I have two xampp versions in my machine one have `php version 5.4` and other having 7.1(recently installed.) I usually use composer command to download laravel. previously i get laravel version 5.0.X when i download because of my `php vesrion(5.4)` but even after installing new xampp(having php version 7) composer is downloading laravel 5.0.x only. When i check my php version it is showing 5.4 now how can i choose or connect latest php version to composer so that i will get latest laravel version.

Comment: XAMPP on what OS

Comment: The `composer` command is just a convenience script. I guess you can always type the full path of everything: `/full/path/to/php /full/path/to/composer.phar` and create custom scripts or aliases to the extent of your shell capacities.

Comment: @RiggsFolly windows 10

Comment: How have you got 2 XAMPP's installed on the same PC. They both have Apache listening on port 80 and MySQL listening on 3306. I would guess you only really have one installed and one that got overwritten

Comment: @RiggsFolly No, both have different ports for apache and mysql. Both servers running fine.

Comment: And different names for the Apache service and the MySQL service?

Comment: Have you checked your Windows PATH, might be that is set to the old version fodler structure. I believe XAMPP does set the PATH

Comment: You should install two separate composer instances, and set appropriate php.exe path for it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly No different names but i changed port numbers and yes my windows PATH is set to old version now can i add new version and both can exist ?

Comment: I personally would remove all from the path, and write a littel batch file to run before doing and PHP CLI work to associate the specific PHP folder to the path that I want to use at this point in time. See [this answer I gave for WAMPServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597067/how-to-run-php-from-windows-command-line/16289254#16289254) for example. Which copes better with multiple versions for Apache/PHP/MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found the solution. I changed my composer path to new php version and now getting what i want.

Comment: You could explain how you did this, :-(

Comment: there is another way https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/change-composer-php-version-without-uninstalling-composer , worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I set my Environment variables as follow:

- change name of respective document xampp that contains your project I want to launch.
  [my system context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nG5fn.png)