# Cannot update Laravel 5.4 to 5.5 composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, updates

When I tried to update Laravel 5.5 from 5.4, it is show errors.

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0",
        "intervention/image": "^2.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

This is my composer.json file.
When I use command **composer update**, this is show.

```
Problem 1
        - This package requires php >=7.0 but your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
      Problem 2
        - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.5.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.0].
        - laravel/framework v5.5.0 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
      Problem 3
        - phpunit/phpunit 6.3.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
        - phpunit/phpunit 6.2.4 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
        - phpunit/phpunit 6.2.3 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
        - phpunit/phpunit 6.2.2 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
        - phpunit/phpunit 6.2.1 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
        - phpunit/phpunit 6.2.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
        - phpunit/phpunit 6.1.4 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
        - phpunit/phpunit 6.1.3 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
        - phpunit/phpunit 6.1.2 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
        - phpunit/phpunit 6.1.1 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
        - phpunit/phpunit 6.1.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
        - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.9 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
        - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.8 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
        - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.7 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
        - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.6 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
        - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.5 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
        - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.4 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
        - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.3 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
        - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.2 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
        - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.13 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
        - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.12 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
        - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.11 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
        - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.10 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
        - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.1 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
        - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
        - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit ~6.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[6.0.0, 6.0.1, 6.0.10, 6.0.11, 6.0.12, 6.0.13, 6.0.
    2, 6.0.3, 6.0.4, 6.0.5, 6.0.6, 6.0.7, 6.0.8, 6.0.9, 6.1.0, 6.1.1, 6.1.2, 6.1.3, 6.1.4, 6.2.0, 6.2.1, 6.2.2, 6.2.3, 6.2.4, 6.3.0].
```

My PHP version is 7.0.10 and I use wamp.

Comment: according to the error your php version is 5.6.25?

Comment: The error indicates that composer is seeing PHP 5.6, what version is showing when you `php -v`?

Comment: If you type "php -v" in your console what you get?

Comment: PHP 5.6.25 (cli) (built: Aug 18 2016 11:40:20)

Comment: How I edit this

Comment: Why did you think you were running 7.x? Did you update PHP?

Comment: I had a simliar problem using a plesk server, the site was configured to run on 7+ and the cli was php 5.6~. Ended up creating an alias to the php7 cli until the server admin updated the cli simlink

Comment: In wamp I has been used 7.0.10 but cli version is 5.6

Comment: See this, only follow the steps for 7.x: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597067/how-to-run-php-from-windows-command-line/16289254#16289254

Answer (score 3):

Your PHP version is 5.6

```
This package requires php >=7.0 but your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

So change your PHP version to PHP 7.0 and run:

```
composer install
```

Comment: You should probably take into account that a) `composer.lock` exists, b) `composer.json` has been edited manually, and thus, it would be better to run `composer require --update-with-dependencies laravel/framework:^5.5`. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

i had similar issue in the past.. this happens with wamp.. check your php version using command prompt.. sometimes wamp shows v7 but the project keeps using older version in the background.
or create a route on laravel to show php version.. it will confirm what the issue is.

Comment: phpinfo() show PHP Version 5.6.25. In wamp I clicked 7.0.10. How I change cli version.

Comment: Include the wamp's PHP executable path in your PATH or run composer like this `C:\Wamp\Path\Php\php.exe composer install` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597067/how-to-run-php-from-windows-command-line?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: you need to update your php version for cli. google update php cli for windows and you will find many guides. once that is done, you need to update your wamp php.ini files and then restart wamp.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `composer.lock` file & run `composer install` again

Answer (score 0):

Try composer install --ignore-platform-reqs