# Minimum PHP version...!! CakePHP 3.4.7 (Wamp / Xampp)

Tags: php, cakephp, xampp, wamp

I Hope you can help me. I'm trying to "Cake bake" my proyect in the cmd, but it always says

**Minimum PHP version: 5.6.0. You are using: 5.5.12.**

Actually I'm using the 7.1.10 version of php. I've been testing with Xampp and Wamp both with a 7.x php

My cakePhp version is 3.4.7, and I don't know if I need to change some file.

Thanks

Comment: Using 7 on the webserver side doesn't mean you're using 7 on the command line. What does `php --version` say?

Comment: You're right. It says **PHP 5.5.12**
Recently I change manually the php, but I didn't erase the old folder, And now It works FINE.
Thanks for your time friend.

Comment: You're most welcome. Added an answer. :-)

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597067/how-to-run-php-from-windows-command-line/16289254#16289254) for how to setup WAMPServer to use any of the versions of PHP that you have installed within WAMPServer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer:

It's entirely possible to have a different version of PHP on the webserver and the command line. Ensuring the version is the one you expect can be done by `php --version` (CLI) or outputting `phpinfo()` (on the webserver).

In this case, CLI needs to be updated to match the webserver.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597067/how-to-run-php-from-windows-command-line/16289254#16289254) for how to setup WAMPServer to use any of the versions of PHP that you have installed within WAMPServer