# using php7 in wampserver and php -v giving php 5

Tags: php, windows, wampserver, php-5.6, php-7.1

I'm using wampserver installed on windows 10. I choosed php 7.1.9 like in the picture: 
[image: Screenshot]

But when i run the command php -v i got:

```
PHP 5.6.31 (cli) (built: Jul  5 2017 22:24:51) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group 
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

and i must install some plugins compatible only with php7
how can i resolve this probem?

Comment: first remove, all the instances of PHP then install php 7

Comment: Sounds similar to - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597067/how-to-run-php-from-windows-command-line - what does your `phpinfo()` show (the cli could be different)?

Comment: Basically you should NEVER add a version of PHP to your Windows PATH. I assume you have done so, otherwise running a `>php -v` would not find the `php.exe`