# Wamp 3.0.6 server can not run Composer and Symfony

Tags: symfony, composer-php, wamp

Please  I need help on this project, I have wamp server to run the project on symphony.Look at the error display on my web browser ,when load the project from wamp server

If I run this code from my command prompt see the results `php app/check.php`

[image]

If I run this code from my command prompt see the results `php app/check.php`

[image]

`php app/console server:run`

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Can you please put more work in formatting your question properly? I'll do that for you this time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you also have XAMPP installed on your system, or did at one time.

See the line that says

```
Configuration file used in PHP : C:\xampp\php\php.ini
                                    ^^^^^
```

I would suggest that you check your Windows PATH. I guess XAMPP might have added it's own PHP version into the PATH.

Alternatively you could uninstall XAMPP, **but make sure you back everything up, code/databases etc before you uninstall it.**

WAMPServer does not need anything placed on the Windows PATH, and if you do it makes switching versions of PHP far more complicated and prone to mistakes.

[Have a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597067/how-to-run-php-from-windows-command-line-in-wampserver/16289254#16289254) for how to make the PHP CLI as flexible as WAMPServer when it comes to running PHP code on different versions of PHP from the command line.

It also looks like you have not istalled composer. Follow the instructions on how to instal composed from the error messages. Or [have a look at the composer site for help](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md)