# Laravel - could not find driver when migrating

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo

Hello I'm using latest version of Laravel, PHP 7.1.9 and MySQL 5.7.19. I'm also using WAMP stack.

When I run the command:

```
php artisan migrate
```

I get the following error: 
[image]

I googled a lot and I' m 100% sure my php.ini file does not have the driver line commented out and the driver is properly working, as seen here: 
[image]

The driver is obviously present:
[image]

Also the path to extension dir is absolute:

```
extension_dir ="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.1.9/ext/"
```

What else can I do? This thing is driving me crazy

Comment: Did you check your db config in the .env file?

Comment: Go into the source code and track down the exceptions and how the error is caused.

Comment: db config and .env files were fine, the problem was that CLI uses older PHP version (the driver line was commented out there) and I was editing the 7.1.9 version. Thank you guys for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 `php.ini` files in the WAMPServer implementation.

One for APACHE which is the one accessed from the menu system and one in each `wamp\bin\php\phpx.y.z` folder

As you are using the PHP CLI you have to check that all the required extensions are also activated in PHP you are using for the CLI `wamp\bin\php\phpx.y.z`

Do this from the command line

```
php --ini
```

It should show you something like this

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.29\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Look at this param `Loaded Configuration File:` to see which `php.ini` file you should be checking.

> This post may also be useful to you for making a batch file to run from the command prompt to switch easily from one version of PHP CLI to another from the command window [How To Run PHP From Windows Command Line in WAMPServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597067/how-to-run-php-from-windows-command-line-in-wampserver/16289254#16289254)

Comment: This is it, CLI uses the 5.6.31 PHP version and of course I was editing the .ini file of 7.1.9 version. Works perfectly now, thank you! Will accept answer as correct soon as possible.

Comment: ALso read the other answer I linked to will be useful if you want to use PHP7.1.9 as the PHP CLI version on a command prompt