# How to have different php.ini file for different PHP versions in WampServer?

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver

I'm using WampServer 3, and I have two versions of PHP (PHP 5.6 and PHP 7.2).

How can I config WAMP to use a different php.ini file for different PHP versions?

Answer (score 0):

WAMPServer already uses a different `php.ini` file for each version of PHP.

Start WAMPSevrer and activate one of the versions of PHP.

```
wampmanager->PHP->version-> (select one of the php versions installed)
```

Using the menus on the wampmanager in the system tray, edit `php.ini`

```
wampmanager->PHP->php.ini
```

This opens `php.ini` in your default editor. Make any amendments you want to make. Save `php.ini`

Switch the version of PHP, using the menus

```
wampmanager->PHP->version-> (select the other version of PHP installed)
```

Using the menus on the wampmanager in the system tray, edit `php.ini`

```
wampmanager->PHP->php.ini
```

This opens `php.ini` in your default editor. Make any amendments you want to make for this version of PHP. Save `php.ini`

> This will effect only the `php.ini` file used by Apache. If you want to also switch the version of PHP used by the CLI, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597067/how-to-run-php-from-windows-command-line-in-wampserver/16289254#16289254) and build yourself a little `.cmd` file to add the correct PHP version to the PATH each time you run the command window.