# there is wamp server path (c /wamp64) into windows path environment variable in C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.1.16 C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.1.16

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I update PHP version and change environment variable PATH to my PHP directory `C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.1.16`
After that I have WAMP error:

> there is wamp server path (c /wamp64) into windows path environment
>   variable in C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.1.16 C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.1.16

Anyone knows the solution?

Comment: Check if you don't have `c://wamp64` in PATH

Comment: You should NEVER put a PHP folder on the PATH when using WAMPServer

Comment: Because it is not needed for running the web server, and if you want to use the PHP CLI [take a look at this answer for how to create a `.cmd` file to associate a PHP version to the PATH temporarily during a windows commend session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597067/how-to-run-php-from-windows-command-line-in-wampserver/16289254#16289254)

Comment: but when i romove it there is something like that in mcd : PHP is not  recognised as an internal or external ...

Comment: Look at my second comment for how to do that. Remember with WAMPServer you can have 20 versions of PHP added into WAMPServer. Using a cmd file to do the add to path means you can pick any of these versions to use from PHP CLI

Comment: But the main reason for NOT adding the PHP to the global PATH is when you upgrade to another PHP version you will forget to amend the global PATH