# while running wamp (php 5.6) and xampp (7.2) in same machine, same time xampp is not taking php 7.2 version, how to overcome it?

Tags: php, xampp, wamp

In my windows machine, i already had wamp with php 5.6.

Now i installed xampp with php 7.2.9

But `C:\xampp>php -v` shows `PHP 5.6.25`.

I want xampp with php 7.2 how can i achieve this.
[image]

my httpd.xampp.conf file has the following:

```
<IfModule env_module>
    SetEnv MIBDIRS "C:/xampp/php/extras/mibs"
    SetEnv MYSQL_HOME "\\xampp\\mysql\\bin"
    SetEnv OPENSSL_CONF "C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf"
    SetEnv PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR "C:\\xampp\\php"
    SetEnv PHPRC "C:\\xampp\\php"
    SetEnv TMP "\\xampp\\tmp"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It looks like you've still got the directory containing the older 5.6 binary in your environment `%PATH%` variable - you'll need to update this to point to the new one.

Comment: @iainn, you are right, updated the environment variable from wampp/php to xampp/php, its working now.

Comment: Why not install one of the many WAMPServer ADDON's one of which is PHP7.2.9 or go all the way to PHP 7.2.10 if you like. [ADDONS can be found here](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net) or sourceforge if you prefer

Comment: But the most likely reason for XAMPP not finding its version of PHP is that you have added the WAMPServer version of PHP to your PATH. WAMPServer does not do this, and does not need this to be done. [See this answer for how to run the PHP CLI on WAMPServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597067/how-to-run-php-from-windows-command-line-in-wampserver/16289254#16289254) or come to that any windows instance with more than one version of PHP