# After updation Wamp Server 3.1.4 showing error

Tags: wamp, wampserver, wamp64

I just updated Wamp Server 3.1.4. Now Wamp shows error in context menu , that when clicked shows this message:

> Sorry,
>
> There is an error.
>
> There is Wampserver path (F:/wamp64) into Windows PATH environnement
>   variable: (F:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10)
>
> It seems that a PHP installation is declared in the environment
>   variable PATH F:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10
>
> Wampserver does not use, modify or require the PATH environment
>   variable. Using a PATH on Wampserver or PHP version is detrimental to
>   the proper functioning of Wampserver.
>
> Press ENTER to continue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to add the PHP folder to the Windows PATH when using WAMPServer. In fact you should not do that at all, this error is telling you that.

WAMPServer will configure the correct PHP to use within Apache when you change PHP versions using the wampmanager icon in the system tray.

Remove `F:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10` from the Windows PATH and the error will go away.

The reason is of course because you could have more than one version of PHP installed within WAMPServer.

If you want to run the PHP CLI from a command windows you should create yourself a little batch file like suggested in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16289254/2310830

Comment: Hello, I am already removed php7.0.10 from our system. But still showing the same error.

Comment: Did you remove any reference to the PHP folder from the widows PATH?

Comment: Yes, I removed php7.0.10 folder completely. But again I have reinstalled the php7.0.10 same destination. But showing the same error.

Comment: NO, Did you remove the directory from the PATH?

Comment: Yes i removed the directory