# wamp say php version is 7.2 but "where php" is 7.1

Tags: php, laravel, wamp

Hi I am installing laravel 6.0. so I update my php version to 7.2 but I am having this error
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
  Problem 1
    - This package requires php ^7.2 but your HHVM version does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for doctrine/lexer 1.2.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/lexer[1.2.0].
    - doctrine/lexer 1.2.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for laravel/framework v6.14.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.14.0].
    - laravel/framework v6.14.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 4
    - Installation request for laravel/tinker v2.2.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/tinker[v2.2.0].
    - laravel/tinker v2.2.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 5
    - Installation request for monolog/monolog 2.0.2 -> satisfiable by monolog/monolog[2.0.2].
    - monolog/monolog 2.0.2 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 6
    - Installation request for symfony/css-selector v5.0.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/css-selector[v5.0.4].
    - symfony/css-selector v5.0.4 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 7
    - Installation request for symfony/mime v5.0.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/mime[v5.0.4].
    - symfony/mime v5.0.4 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 8
    - Installation request for symfony/service-contracts v2.0.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/service-contracts[v2.0.1].
    - symfony/service-contracts v2.0.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 9
    - Installation request for symfony/translation-contracts v2.0.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/translation-contracts[v2.0.1].
    - symfony/translation-contracts v2.0.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.1.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 10
    - Installation request for phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 5.0.0 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[5.0.0].
    - phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 5.0.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 11
    - Installation request for phpunit/php-code-coverage 7.0.10 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[7.0.10].
    - phpunit/php-code-coverage 7.0.10 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 12
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 8.5.2 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[8.5.2].
    - phpunit/phpunit 8.5.2 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 13
    - Installation request for sebastian/global-state 3.0.0 -> satisfiable by sebastian/global-state[3.0.0].
    - sebastian/global-state 3.0.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 14
    - Installation request for sebastian/type 1.1.3 -> satisfiable by sebastian/type[1.1.3].
    - sebastian/type 1.1.3 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 15
    - doctrine/lexer 1.2.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.26) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - egulias/email-validator 2.1.15 requires doctrine/lexer ^1.0.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/lexer[1.2.0].
    - Installation request for egulias/email-validator 2.1.15 -> satisfiable by egulias/email-validator[2.1.15].
```

from suggestions, I check "where PHP"

it says,

```
E:\wamp64\www\poms>where php
E:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.26\php.exe
```

again my wanp is already set to php 7.2 even the phpinfo() say the same thing.

how can I solve this?

thank you so much in advance!

Comment: The version of PHP used under Apache is not always the same as the version used by the CLI

Comment: thanks @RiggsFolly for the comment. how can I fix this?

Comment: Edit your original question. I can't install laravel 6 even my php is 7.2

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597067/how-to-run-php-from-windows-command-line-in-wampserver/16289254#16289254