# Running php artisan serve command with different php versions

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel 5.6 Project which is running with **PHP Version 7.10** and another Laravel 7.x project with **PHP version 7.4**. I defined the PHP path in Windows 10 `Environment Variable` and every time I have to change the PHP `Environment Variable` to run each project.

any solution to prevent from this redundant work?

Comment: Operating System?

Comment: I'm using Windows

Comment: Then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16289254/2310830) may give you some useful clues

Comment: so with batch file I can add the php path before the php artisan serve and run every project with the required php version?

Comment: Yes thats the idea

Comment: C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.33\php.exe artisan serve --host=127.0.0.1 --port=8000

Comment: Well I wrote a batch file that accepted a parameter of the version of PHP you wanted to use so you run `>phppath 7.1.0` and then `>php artisan serve --host=127.0.0.1 --port=8000`

Comment: Is Laravel 5.6 not compatible with  PHP 7.4 ?

Comment: it is throwing errors when running in my project

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For `Windows`:

to run different projects with its required PHP version you can include the required PHP path before writing `artisan serve`:

```
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.33\php.exe artisan serve --host=127.0.0.1 --port=8000
```

```
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.4.9\php.exe artisan serve --host=127.0.0.1 --port=8500
```

---

For Linux (`Ubuntu`):

```
/usr/bin/php8.0 artisan serve --host=127.0.0.1 --port=8000
```

Answer (score 1):

For Windows Xampp. you can set path like this. in my case xampp is in "C" drive.

```
/c/xampp/php/php.exe artisan serve
```