# edit php configuration (php.ini) in wamp

Tags: php, wamp

i have installed wamp for mysql, apache and php, and it's working fine
when i type php -v in console i'm getting php version 7.4.9

```
PHP 7.4.9 (cli) (built: Aug  4 2020 11:52:41) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

but i have edited the following php.ini in the version 7.4.9 folder, and then restarted wamp services but the settings didn't get updated.

what did i miss to do ? or my wamp configuration is messed up ?

Comment: _Small Note_ With WAMPServer you should NEVER add the PHP folder to the PATH. Instead [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597067/how-to-run-php-from-windows-command-line-in-wampserver/16289254#16289254)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe your system $PATH contains php 7.4 folder
but maybe wamp is using another version

to get the right php.ini:

1. click once on wamp icon in the windows taskbar
2. hover php to display
3. php details click on php.ini on the little menu

the following image describe the process wamp php.ini file

[image]

Comment: indeed!, the php.ini was located in apache_directory\bin\php.ini, thank you

Comment: While the image answers the question easily, if somehow the link is down it'll be impossible to know what you're talking about. It'd help if you posted the instructions along with the image to deal with this potential situation.

Comment: you are right, i edited my answer describing all steps, thanks