# Is there a way to switch PHP version between 7.4 and 8.0 without making changes to Environment Variables?

Tags: php, windows, apache, wamp, wamp64

My **current** environment is:

1. PHP7.4
2. Windows 10
3. WAMP

I want to work on different projects but both are on different PHP versions. I face a hurdle in changing the environment files. Is there a way to simply change the PHP version from the WAMP server?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You might consider something like Docker, to run entirely isolated development environments.

Comment: If you have put the PHP folder into the Windows PATH then you have made an error!! First of all its not necessary and second because WAMPServer is so flexible on versions of everything it really limits that flexibility (as you have now found out)

Comment: Remove any references to WAMPServer folders from the PATH and see [this answer for how to simply and flexibly use which ever version of PHP you want to from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597067/how-to-run-php-from-windows-command-line-in-wampserver/16289254#16289254)